# What should I be using with ASP.Net MVC, NHibernate, LINQ, EF?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-access

Hi I posted a question a little earlier and I had some replies that I should look at some different technologies. Which of the above (or other feel free to mention) is the most popular or best supported.

As stated in my earlier question I am learning ASP.Net MVC. I come from a Java struts background but I am prepared to try and learn what the majority of people are using in conjunction with ASP.Net MVC?

Edit:
I did a quick Google Trends to try and pickup which is the most popular (assumming most searched = most popular = best supported, yes I know, a notion that is fraught with short falls) then LINQ is the best way to go:

[Google Trends](http://www.google.com/trends?q=Nhibernate%2C+Linq%2C+entity+framework)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ to SQL is the easiest of them all. I would suggest you starting with LINQ to SQL.

NHibernate may seem closer to Java's Hibernate but I strongly suggest LiNQ to SQL as a starting point.

Comment: #IF DEF Devil's Advocate: Doesn't that make Linq to SQL a distraction?

Answer (score 1):

[NHibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NHibernate) is by far the best ORM in the .NET world.

Comment: +1 Also, the barrier of entry has been lowered significantly because of Fluent NHibernate - there's no reason NOT to start out with NHibernate!